# How to check the authenticity of docker container and pulled image?

Tags: linux, docker, shell, nexus

Problem Statement:
My task was to  determine whether the image I just pulled from Nexus is genuine or not corrupt due to a network problem or another issue.

There may be other ways to do this check, however I choose to use the Digest sh256 checksum.

I've added solution to this statement below in comments.

Comment: And? Did that sha256 checksum check (pun intended) work? What is your question then? If it didn't work, what exactly did you do, what happened, and what did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? See also [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some struggle i got the solution for this problem:

```
#!/bin/sh
NEXUS_URL=##NEXUS##
DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME="abc"
DOCKER_IMAGE_VER="1.0.0-1"

NEXUS_CHECKSUM=$(curl "https://$NEXUS_URL:5443/service/rest/v1/search?docker.imageTag=$DOCKER_IMAGE_VER&docker.imageName=$DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME" | grep "sha256" | awk '{print $3}' | sed 's/"//g')

PULLED_CHECKSUM=$(podman image ls --digests --format '{{.Digest}}' $NEXUS_URL:5000/tas/$DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME:$DOCKER_IMAGE_VER |  cut -d ':' -f 2)

echo "$NEXUS_CHECKSUM : $PULLED_CHECKSUM"

if [[ $NEXUS_CHECKSUM==$PULLED_CHECKSUM ]];then
   echo "Image is not courrupt"
else
   echo "Image is Corrupt"
fi
```